# Alinhamento com FlexBox

Tags: html5, css3

Estou com dificuldade em fazer um projeto com usando **Flexbox**.

Veja **[AQUI](http://www.famigerado.com.br/tela/)** meu projeto em andamento

Essas caixas vermelhas estão distribuídas usando **Flexbox**, a quantidade de caixas vai variar de 1 até 400, ou seja, é preciso distribuir corretamente.

Queria que, se tivessem 400 caixas, elas ficassem menores, para que coubesse tudo na tela. E se tivessem 3 caixas, elas ficassem maiores, mais bem distribuídas.

Como podeira fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FfJNU/65/)*** para estudo do código.

***Solução:***
Para criar um **`<div class="main">`** que possa ter entre 1 e 400 (ou até mais) **`<div></div>`** dentro de si, de forma que eles se preencham responsivamente, basta aplicar ao **Div Pai `.main`** as seguintes regras CSS:

```
.main {
width:100%;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

E dentro dessa **Div Pai `.main`** aplicam-se as seguintes regras, para que seus descendentes comportem-se responsivamente em linha, da esquerda para direita `ltr`.

```
.main div {
-webkit-flex:1 1 auto;
flex:1 1 auto;
min-width: 100px;

/* A propriedade min-width serve para definir uma largura mínima, evitando que as divs
   fiquem muito comprimidas, e assim que as divs da linha tiverem atingido suas larguras
   mínimas, a ultima div da linha é passada para linha de baixo afim de liberar espaço
   para que as outras da mesma linha sejam comprimidas ainda mais. */

/*
    A propriedade FLEX é uma atalho para a mesma coisa escrita abaixo
    -webkit-flex-basis:auto;
    -webkit-flex-shrink:1;
    -webkit-flex-grow:1;
*/
}
```